# Checking index key used by rank() function in sql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, ranking

With `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 where condition1 = condition1 and condition2 = condition2` you can check the index key being used if you have any.

If you have  `SELECT * RANK() OVER (ORDER BY condition3 DESC, condition4 ASC) AS table2 FROM table1` , can you index the condition3 and condition4 for the rank() function? Heck, how do you even check the index being used by the rank() function here if you have done indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes to both of your questions, and your rank query should benefit from the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table1 (condition3 DESC, condition4);
```

Running `EXPLAIN` on the above query should show this index being used.

Comment: Right, ur solutions works. Coz previously I was doing `SELECT * RANK() OVER (ORDER BY condition3 DESC, condition4 ASC) AS table2 FROM table1 WHERE condition1 = true` and I had two indexes key , one on both condition 3 and 4, another one on condition 1. And running `EXPLAIN` on this give me the index on condition 1 only. If I remove the `WHERE condition1 = true` from the statement, then  it will give me the index on condition3 and 4. ANy idea why?

Comment: @tnkh When you add that `WHERE` clause, the previous index in my answer might not be usable by MySQL.  Instead, try using `(condition1, condition3 DESC, condition4)`.  In general, if an index cannot _cover_ the entire query, then the database might not use it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Mixing directions (DESC and ASC) only works if running MySQL 8.0 and there is an `INDEX` with matching directions.  (Or is there some magic that I don't know about?)

Comment: @RickJames What would be your suggested index in this case?  MySQL 8+ can be assumed here given the use of `RANK`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Touche; obviously 8.0.  First, I want to experiment to see if any index is actually used in that context.  (My experience with windowing and CTEs is that performance verges on "terrible".)  If you happen to have a complete test case, that might get me moving faster.